# subquery inside select of Laravel with Eloquent ORM with

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to execute following raw query with laravel eloquent ORM:
`SELECT *,(SELECT country FROM tbl_sim_numbers WHERE highland_id= b.highland_id) as country1,(SELECT operator FROM tbl_sim_numbers WHERE highland_id= b.highland_id) AS operator1 FROM tbl_sim_distributions b ORDER BY b.created_at`

on eloquent ORM of laravel. I tried:

```
$sub = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT *,(SELECT country FROM tbl_sim_numbers WHERE highland_id= b.highland_id) as country1,(SELECT operator FROM tbl_sim_numbers WHERE highland_id= b.highland_id) AS operator1 FROM tbl_sim_distributions b
                 ORDER BY b.created_at"));

        $pdfGenObjForList = DB::table( DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub") )
            ->mergeBindings($sub->getQuery());
```

However above code gives error.Someone,please help.

Comment: please post the error ..

Comment: Show your BD schema and your relationships then only people can help you.

Comment: @Amit,the raw query works perfectly, only I need to transform it to laravel ORM statements.